# In Ember How Should I Call a Function in the Controller Whenever A Property Changes

Tags: javascript, templates, binding, controller, ember.js

I would like the function `exampleFunction` to be called every time `exampleProperty' changes.
How should I set that up? Seems this has changed recently. I'm using 1.0.0-RC1.

The template:

```
   <div id="container">
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="exampleProperty"}}
    </div>
```

The controller:

```
ExampleApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  exampleProperty: "example",

  exampleFunction: function() {
    console.log("exampleProperty was changed");
  }

});
```

Comment: Javascript, but not ember?, you would use "on" with "keyup" to call a callback.

Comment: Clarified the question by putting Ember in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would define exampleFunction as an observer. The most straightforward syntax is to use the 'observes' method on `Function` as such:

```
exampleFunction: function () {
    console.log("property changed");
}.observes('exampleProperty')
```

You can read more about observers (and more) at the Ember guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/

Answer (score 2):

You would create a "observes" property.

```
ExampleApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  exampleProperty: "example",

  exampleFunction: function() {
    console.log("exampleProperty was changed");
  }.observes("exampleProperty")

});
```

Comment: Sorry. 3 seconds too late ;)